Homework questions
Do we want these on QSE or not? There is even a tag homework that has been used 40 times already.
Latest example of a "homework" type question is for example here.
I guess the general issue is when people show no effort: clearly, we don't want QSE to be a go-to sight for solutions.
But do we even want homework type of questions here when OPs show effort?
From my end, I am not against it: homework questions can be interesting sometimes and at least give us a chance to see how quantitative finance courses evolve over time. But I guess we need to enforce two things:

Making sure the OPs mark the questions as homework
They show genuine effort

Any other thoughts?

I share your perspective in its entirety

@Jan Stuller I  think the question you linked to in your original post should have been downvoted because it showed lack of effort.  By the way, I have  no idea how to solve the question and  if I could would I get better investment returns?

I believe we want people who are learning to come here and post. That means, homework style questions. For example, a person who  is doing self-study
may post a question from a text book and his wrong solution to the problem asking for help. That is something I have done.
A while back, I had a question down voted, I feel unfairly, because it
was a homework question. Here is a link to the question:
Calculating the volatility for Black Scholes
I feel this question should be allowed. It did not have the homework tag and I am thinking it did not exist back then. Not sure.
I have had friends post to several different stack exchanges and a couple of them felt that some of the real experts here were more interesting in down voting their questions then proving real help.
